# REST api: Where to set the dot-format part?

Tags: api, rest, format

In our company we will introduce a REST api to fetch hourly measure values of some system variables for various systems.

The REST API will look something like this:

```
https://api.fubar.com/v1/hourlyMeasureValues/2014021723-2014032305/system/4711,4712,4713/variables/speed,pressure,temperature?sortOrder=-time&valueTypes=avg,min,max
```

This will fetch measured values

- for the time range 21-Feb-2014 23:00 to 23-Mar-2014
- for our systems 4711, 4712 and 4713
- for the variables speed, pressure and temperature

in a sort order "time descending" and we will fetch the hourly average, the hourly minimum and the hourly maximum.

Now the question: There are some alternatives for setting the result content type (JSON, XML, CSV).

1. Put "**Accept: application/json**" etc in the Header
2. Add a query parameter for type, e.g. [...]valueTypes=avg,min,max **&type=xml**
3. Add **.format** in the base URL

We want to go for solution 3.

Would this be the correct location?

```
https://api.fubar.com/v1/hourlyMeasureValues.csv/2014021723-2014032305/system/4711,4712,4713/variables/speed,pressure,temperature?sortOrder=-time&valueTypes=avg,min,max
```

or somewhere else?

Comment: If you are going with the third solution. You have to specify a millions of pages or URL, Am I right ? That is poor option. It is my opinion.

Comment: Content type negotiation should be done using the `Accept` header. Your client should send in the header what type of content it expects, your server generates the content accordingly and sends the response with the corresponding `Content-Type` header set. For me this is the REST way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are going to abuse REST for generating reports. I do not like idea of putting systems into URL - for me each system is another REST resource. Variables looks like filtering of resource content - it is better to use query param for filtering. My proposal is:

```
https://api.fubar.com/v1/system/4711/hourlyMeasureValues.json?
range=2014021723,2014032305&variables=speed,pressure,temperature
&sortOrder=-time&valueTypes=avg,min,max
```

If you really need it for several systems in one call then I would change it to this form:

```
https://api.fubar.com/v1/reports/hourlyMeasureValues.json?
systems=4711,4712,4713&range=2014021723,2014032305
&variables=speed,pressure,temperature&sortOrder=-time&valueTypes=avg,min,max
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using REST over HTTP then you should following the principles of [HTTP content negotiation](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (See page 71).

Depending on what you are doing, you may need more than just the content type to achieve proper content negotiation. For instance, the a given client may still want to receive the content in a particular encoding or language.

But at any rate, the HTTP way is to set all those in headers.

```
GET /myurl
Accept: application/json
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-7
Accept-Language: en
```

And the server use those to determine what is the proper response to send back to the client.

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-7
Content-Language: en
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" location - that's a meaningless concept. Your API framework should be able to suss out the extension wherever you put it in the URI. Given the URI as it exists now, that seems like the most reasonable place to me.

Note that I agree with both Piotr and Edwin.